# How to setup HHVM for PHPUnit in PhpStorm

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm, hhvm

How could I run my unit tests in PhpStorm 8 with HHVM as its interpreter?

PhpStorm 8 supports PHPUnit 4 which that supports HHVM and I could run my test suite on termianl with HHVM but I do not know how to config PhpStorm 8 in order to run my unit tests with HHVM.

Comment: Same as as for "normal" PHPUnit testing in PhpStorm -- http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Testing+PHP+Applications . **Possible problems** are: **1)** PhpStorm uses custom .php helper/wrapper script for integration purposes -- I'm not sure if it is compatible with HHVM; **2)** PhpStorm uses your project default PHP interpreter (`Settings | PHP`) when launching tests -- I have no idea if it will recognise HHVM as an interpreter (as it checks the output searching for some info)

Comment: 1. I guess PhpStorm 8's wrapper should be compatible with HHVM because of its PhpUnit 4 support. 2. That's exactly my point, I do not know how to config PhpStorm 8's php interpreter to HHVM. If I could do that, the problem may be solved.

Comment: 1) Why it *"should be"*? Does PhpStorm officially supports HHVM? -- No. If it has no support **in general** then why specific part HAS to have such **special** support? Surely -- it would be fantastic if it would -- no objections here. So far it does not look like they have any plans to have it in nearest future (based on current status of few tickets): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-18817 ; https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-21737

Comment: 2) You mean -- you do not know how to configure PHP Interpreter in PhpStorm (in general) .. and just see if it will recognize it or not? Yes -- I cannot provide you with exact instructions if it is possible, but at least you could see if it would work or not using straight approach.

Comment: I think if PhpStorm is supporting PHPUnit 4, so it also should support HHVM, because PHPUnit 4's support for HHVM is of the its features.
Second "debugging" is fully another story. It does NOT need to support dubugging processes in order to support HHVM as an interpreter.
Third, HACK is a language upon HHVM so supporting HACK has no coherency to support HHVM or not.

Comment: Obviosly PhpStorm will not do any black magic in order to recognize if you have any HHVM installation on your OS or not. So surly one should configure it. But it's not the problem cause I know how to do that but the problem is, it (PhpStorm) is not supporting it I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now by PHPStorm 8.0.2 it becomes possible:

Under the PHP setting, add a new interpreter located in `/usr/bin/hhvm` or `/usr/local/bin/hhvm`