# How I can configure hhvm as an interpreter in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, phpunit, phpstorm, hhvm

How I can configure hhvm as an interpreter in PhpStorm? I have some classes that use hack why I need the test run with hhvm. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Under the PHP setting, add a new interpreter located in /usr/bin/hhvm or /usr/local/bin/hhvm

Comment: Also see http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2015/06/hack-language-support-in-phpstorm-postponed/

Comment: @Vigikaran since version can do this?

Comment: PHPStorm 8.0.2 and above

Comment: @Vigikaran I tested with version 8.0.3 and had no good results. I have set a docker ssh access to another docher has hhvm, putting the interpreter does not accept me I get: env: /usr/bin/hhvm: No such file or directory

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26036090/how-to-setup-hhvm-for-phpunit-in-phpstorm